# Prove that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}|$ exists, then it is equal to the radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

> **a)** Prove that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} | \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}|$ exists, then it is equal to the radius of
>   convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n x^n$.

First assume that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} | \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}|=r$ and $r>0$. From d'Alemebert criterion we know that the series converges if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} x|<1$. From our assumption we have that the series converges whenever $|x|<r$. If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} | \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}|=\infty$ we can easily deduce that the series covnerges for all $x$. I don't know however how to treat the case when $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} | \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}|=0$. Any ideas?

> **b)** Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n x^n$ has the same radius of covergence as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n+m} x^n$ for any
>   $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

From Cauchy-Hadamard we know that the radius of convergence of the first series is given by $\frac{1}{L}$ where $L=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} |c_n|^{1/n}$. So $L$ is defined to be

$$\sup \{x\in\mathbb{R} : |c_n|^{1/n}>x \mbox{ for infinitely many $n$} \}$$

How can I prove the above statement using this very definition of $\limsup$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) Fix $x\ne 0$. Let $A_n$ be $n$-th partial sum for the first series,  $B_n$ be $n$-th partial sum for the second series. Then  the difference $x^mB_n-A_n=A_{m-1}$ does not depend on $n$, so the first series converges iff the second converges.

a)  Can we proceed as follows? From d'Alemebert criterion we know that the series diverges if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} x|>1$. So if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} | \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}|=0$ then the series diverges for any $x\ne 0$.